# Logical operator on named range in a sumproduct, weighted histogram (excel)

Tags: excel

So I wrote some code a few years ago that generates a spreadsheet that does some neat stuff.   It involves doing some weird stuff for a histogram.  I just came across a need to update/use this for a different project, and there is some code in there I really don't entirely understand.

Basically it's a logical operator working on a named range that then gets used in a sumproduct.  And for the life of me I don't entirely get why it works, but it does.  Here's the offending line.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((tblC62>G90)*(tblC62<=G91) * tblC2wgt2)
```

`tblC62` and `tblC2wgt2` reference some paired data. Each record in `tblC62` lines up with a record from `tblC2wgt2`. The purpose is to create a weighted histogram. `tblC2wgt2` provides the weight.  The data is binned by `tblC62` values and the bin range is defined by `G90` and `G91` and `tblC62`. So it will define.

And this works. I've checked it thoroughly. And I don't understand why. It's the `tblC62` logicals being multiplied that that is the most confusing.

Anyways, I have to explain the math to my boss shortly.....so if anyone can explain to me how this code works I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is using the inherent values of the Boolean True/False.  When using them in math they automaticaly revert to their values of 1/0 respectively.

So in:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((tblC62>G90)*(tblC62<=G91) * tblC2wgt2)
```

When `(tblC62>G90)` is true its value is 1 and when false it is 0.  The same with `(tblC62<=G91)`

So when both are true we get `1 * 1` which equals `1`.  If either are false we get `0 * 1` which equals `0`.

Then the result of that is multiplied with `tblC2wgt2`.  So when either or both are false it is `0 * tblC2wgt2 which = 0`.  When both are true we get `1 * tblC2wgt2 = tblC2wgt2`.

The Sumproduct then adds up all the variations.

Comment: ahhhhhh.  So it's really not a sumproduct, not in the traditional sense.  It's just summing everything from the named range that falls within that range and nulling everything else.   Man, thanks a lot.  I really could not understand what I had done there.  I mean seriously, I am going to meet with my manager in 5 minutes.  You really saved my butt.

Comment: @emorris1000 please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.